# Extending react component received by redux connect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it somehow possible to extend component that is being connected by Redux `connect()` function? For example, if I am inside `form-container.js` and I'm using

```
const FormContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Form)
```

Is there a way to override some methods like this:

```
FormContainer.componentDidMount = () => ...
```

Or add custom functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use High order components for this. I'm borrowing this example from [this article](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.20ag417ok)

```
function HigherOrderComponent(WrappedComponent) {
  return class NewComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super(props)
      this.customMethod = this.customMethod.bind(this)
    }
    customMethod() {
      console.log('You called an injected method');
    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} customMethod={this.customMethod} />
    }
  }
}
```

How to use this custom method:

```
import HigherOrderComponent from './HigherOrderComponent'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.customMethod()
  }
  render() {
      ...
  }
}
const MutatedComponent = HigherOrderComponent(MyComponent)
const ConnectedComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MutatedComponent)
```

As far as I know, you cannot override life-cycle methods of a React component. But you can inject methods by using HoC.